# Reordering of NSTableview Rows in View based Tableview

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

As per apple documentation drag and drop `NSTableView` delegate methods are called only for cell based TableViews not for View based. So there is no way to do reordering of rows using drag & drop for view based `NSTableView`?

Answer (score 7):

I have created a [small sample project](https://github.com/besi/mac-quickies/tree/master/OutlineView) which has an `NSOutlineView` where you can add and remove items as well as reorder them. This is not an `NSTableView` but the implementation of the Drag & Drop protocol is basically identical.

I implemented drag and Drop in one go so it's best to look at [this commit](https://github.com/besi/mac-quickies/commit/e8d2c2506349fa00a342c291a0031c40a1f598e3).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is that concept applicable to a NSCollectionView as well?
I am just trying to reorder CollectionItems by drag and drop. Just curious …

Comment: I don't know at the top of my head. However I would assume that this should work there as well, but you'll have to test this. I know that the same concept applies for table views and source lists.

Answer (score 3):

Drag and drop delegate methods get called fine in a view based `NSTableView`. There is a great presentation from WWDC '11 on view based table views, and it includes a lengthy discussion about drag and drop. Worth watching.

Link [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/120/) - requires a login.